# Can't resolve all parameters for ECPair: (?, ?, ?)

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings, bitcoinlib

I try to implement [bitcoinjs-lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bitcoinjs-lib) in a new angular 4 app
What i did :

```
npm install bitcoinjs-lib --save
npm install @types/bitcoinjs-lib --save
```

My app.component.ts :

```
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HDNode, Transaction, ECPair } from 'bitcoinjs-lib'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

  constructor(private ecPair: ECPair){
    console.log(this.ecPair.getAddress())
  }
}
```

Compiled successfully but i get in my browser :

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ECPair: (?, ?, ?).
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:466)
```

Here is ECPair in the node_modules :

```
export class ECPair {
    constructor(d: BigInteger, Q?: null, options?: { compressed?: boolean, network?: Network });

    constructor(d: null | undefined, Q: any, options?: { compressed?: boolean, network?: Network }); // Q should be ECPoint, but not sure how to define such type

    d: BigInteger;

    getAddress(): string;
...
}
```

I understand that he doesn't know how to instantiate it because of the differents parameters type, how can i fix it ? I tried with @Inject but can't resolved too.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide it properly. In your `@NgModule` you should use something like this:

```ts
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    ...
    { ECPair, useFactory:()=>new ECPair(d,Q,options) }
  ]
})
```

Specify appropriate arguments for `d` `Q` and `options`.